# Integrate SAP SuccessFactors Integration Center and Azure Data Lake Store:

Tags: active-directory, integration, azure-data-lake

so I have been trying to use the SuccessFactors integration center to send out a scheduled output of data in CSV format, the destination being a folder on an Azure Data Lake Store.

I have set up the integration content, with the outbound being REST, since I would supposedly hit the Webfhds of the Lake Store. However I’m having a problem with authentication, it keeps giving me error code 401 i.e Unauthorised and that’s due to not having an access token.

Can someone please help out with this problem, also could the authentication be failing because of not having AD integration in the provisioning backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakestore/webhdfs-filesystem-apis

Above link has information on how to authenticate with Azure Active Directory using the Azure Data Lake Store REST API.
You can look at the Core classes in our Java and .Net SDKs as a guide for how they handle the authentication:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/datalake/store/Core.java

https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-net/blob/master/AdlsDotNetSDK/Core.cs